# Get data form CSV to move a file

Tags: shell-script, csv

I have a CSV file with two columns and this information:

```
Column1 | Column2
USA     | Chicago
USA     | Dallas
FR      | France
AUS     | Sydney
AUS     | Perth
```

I have to move all the files where `Column1`  equals `AUS`. For example,

```
mv Sydney* /usr/local/sbin
mv Perth* /usr/local/sbin
```

Is it possible to do this with a shell script without hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/sh

awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="|"
}
/\s*AUS\s*/ {
    region = $2
    gsub(/\s+/, "", region)
    system( sprintf("echo mv '%s' /usr/sbin",  + region))
}

{}
' inputfile.csv
```

You'll need to change the filename and remove the "echo" from the system command.

Comment: Note that both `$1` and `$2` would include whitespace if you use `|` as delimiter. Also, we usually try to give full answers rather than pointers in general directions.

Comment: Fair enough. Is that better?